# How to align contents in different containers using only css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to build a `Pricing Table`similar to one shown below.

[image: on-full-width]

Following are my requirements

- The `Get Started` button should be on same horizontal level
- The containers have to be of same height irrespective of the content (The no. of points & length of description in the two can vary as shown)
- These two containers should stack one above other on low screen width

here is a minimum snippet for my current solution using JS

```js
findTallest = function () {
  var tallestByGroupNum = {}
  $(".item-contents").each(
    function () {
      var grpNum = $(this).parent().attr('data-group-num');
      // !< instead of > to support undefined values
      if (!($(this).height() < tallestByGroupNum[grpNum] )) {
        tallestByGroupNum[grpNum] = $(this).height();
      }
    }
  );

  $(".item-box").height(
    function () {
      return tallestByGroupNum[$(this).attr('data-group-num')];
    }
  );
};

$(window).resize(findTallest);
findTallest();
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

.item-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.pricingCard {
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-6 pricingCard">
    <h1>Free</h1>

    <div class="item-box" data-group-num="1">
      <div class="item-contents">
        Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long description
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</button>

    <div class="item-box" data-group-num="2">
      <div class="item-contents">
        <div>Point</div>
        <div>Point</div>
        <div>Point</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 pricingCard">
    <h1>Premium</h1>

    <div class="item-box" data-group-num="1">
      <div class="item-contents">
        Short description
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</button>

    <div class="item-box" data-group-num="2">
      <div class="item-contents">
        <div>Point</div>
        <div>Point</div>
        <div>Point</div>
        <div>Point</div>
        <div>Point</div>
        <div>Point</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

To explain the problem, here's the snippet exluding the JS code. Note that the buttons don't align properly as before.

Also the solution suggested in the comments are similar to this only.

```css
/* Put your css in here */

.item-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.pricingCard {
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-6 pricingCard">
    <h1>Free</h1>

    <div class="item-box" data-group-num="1">
      <div class="item-contents">
        Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long description
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</button>

    <div class="item-box" data-group-num="2">
      <div class="item-contents">
        <div>Point</div>
        <div>Point</div>
        <div>Point</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 pricingCard">
    <h1>Premium</h1>

    <div class="item-box" data-group-num="1">
      <div class="item-contents">
        Short description
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</button>

    <div class="item-box" data-group-num="2">
      <div class="item-contents">
        <div>Point</div>
        <div>Point</div>
        <div>Point</div>
        <div>Point</div>
        <div>Point</div>
        <div>Point</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Again to emphasis on the problem here's the comparison
 [image]

Currently I am using javascript to achieve this. I detect the tallest element and then set the height of the parent container to that.

Here the [link to the plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/NWcC5J?p=preview) on my current implmentation is JS.

Can this be done in css alone (using some bootstrap classes).

Comment: Flex box will allow you to accomplish what you want.

Comment: you can also check out `bootstrap grid`, here is a reference [Bootsrap grid system](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) .

Comment: you can use col-sm-6 col-xs-12 instea dof col-xs-6.

Comment: @Leothelion I appreciate your comment but please first read the requirements. The question is not about implementing responsiveness. It's about aligning contents which are in different containers (bootstrap columns)

Comment: not getting the point. I real all the requirement of yours. So what you need is aligning contents with css only? Please add little bit more info. Thank you

Comment: @Leothelion thanks for the feedback. I have updated the question to include what will if I use only bootstrap grids without my JS snippet.

Comment: pleae check this one https://jsfiddle.net/5jze6pbo/3/

Comment: @Leothelion checked out the fiddle. It is exactly same as my first screenshot. What I want is the 3rd screen shot where the buttons **ALIGNS HORIZONTALLY**

Comment: @Harry sorry but we can  give you reference of litle help.. We just cant give you exact solution..try to play with my fiddle may be you will get your solution as you know your issue in better way.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest** code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for the advice.  I have updated the question by including the snippets (the one showing problem and the one with JS solution)

Comment: @Harry give it a try -> http://www.lottejackson.com/learning/an-equal-height-grid-using-flexbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `flexbox`, I'd do something like this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pricing {
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2em 0;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .pricing {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
.pricing .block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}
@media (max-width: 48em) {
  .pricing .block {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .pricing .block:nth-child(odd) {
    order: -1;
  }
  .pricing .block:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 2em;
  }
}
.pricing header,
.pricing ul {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px silver;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 80%;
}
.pricing header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.pricing button {
  margin-top: auto;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

h1,
h2 {
  margin: 0.125em 0;
}

button {
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing">
  <div class="block">
    <header>
      <h1>Free</h1>
      <h2>0$</h2>
      <p>short description</p>
      <button>Get Started</button>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <header>
      <h1>Premium</h1>
      <h2>5$</h2>
      <p>long description long description long description long description long description long description</p>
      <button>Get Started</button>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <ul>
      <li>Point 1</li>
      <li>Point 2</li>
      <li>Point 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <ul>
      <li>Point 1</li>
      <li>Point 2</li>
      <li>Point 3</li>
      <li>Point 4</li>
      <li>Point 5</li>
      <li>Point 6</li>
      <li>Point 7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! genius answer. changing the order depending of the screen width is awesome. I am accepting this as right answer but just one suggestion I would like to add here:  the line`flex: 1 1 50%;` should be moved to within the media query block so that on small screen the cards would take the least space and don't have empty spacing left

Comment: Sweet. Yep, you should drop this `flex: 1 1 50%` for smaller resolution.

Answer (score 0):

In pure css using bootstrap the only way you are going to achieve this is with two different layouts of these elements. In one you will have your current html - these will be for smaller screen sizes, in the other, you will have a layout where the two top divs are in a `row` and the two bottom divs are in a `row`. This will allow the rows to keep the same height. You then use media queries or hidden classes e.g. `hidden-md` the relevant html. It's not great as it requires duplication of code, but it is a pure css solution.

An example i've put together can be found here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lcs8uLb/) - It needs a lot of work with the styling but you can see how the different elements are displayed at different widths just using bootstrap classes.

I also had to make use of flex-box for the the align-items vertical stretching

Comment: Yes that crossed my mind. Duplicating the code seems like a bad idea, I would rather use JS. The only reason I posted the question is I wanted to know if there is a standard solution to this so that I don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Just saw your fiddle, it does not solve the problem. The buttons are not aligned. I have updated my question to include the snippets and a comparison image to help others to understand the problem.

Comment: to align the buttons you would need to flex them within the divs or apply the same concept to have them in their own row - i can't do all the work for you!